# Unable to find element in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to enter an ID and password on a website using Selenium WebDriver but my code doesn't work. It seems that it can't find an element.

I checked the HTML code and found the value.

**This is my Python code**

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:\Chrome_Driver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://hisnet.handong.edu/')
sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_name('id').send_keys('ㅁ')  
sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('ㅁ')
```

**and this is the HTML code**

```
input type="text" style="color:#000000; height: 16px; width:138px;ime-mode:inactive" name="id" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" placeholder="아이디를 입력하십시오." value=""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are nested frames to negotiate

```
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
#from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'http://hisnet.handong.edu/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name=MainFrame]"))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name=MainFrame]"))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name=id").send_keys("banana")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[type=password]").send_keys("orange")
```

You could use wait condition for frame:

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[type=password]")))
```

Comment: and I don't think I'm really familiar with HTML. could you explain a little bit more plz?

Comment: Very good answer.I am deleting my answer since your code is working fine.

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work means? I ran this and it populated the two boxes on the right hand side.

Comment: ohhh I'm so sorry. I just copy-pasted your code without filling in "Chrome()". it's working. However, I think I need to study more to understand how your code works. thanks a lot

Comment: When you examine the html you will see your element sits with a parent <frame> which also sits within a parent <frame>. To access your element you need to switch to those.

Comment: ok I understand why you're using "switch_to.frame" but I still don't know why you're using _css_selector. could you explain please?

Comment: modern browsers are optimized for css. css governs page styling. This helps with fast and responsive web design. So, selecting the element by css selectors is generally the faster method for getting an element.

Comment: The only thing I would suggest to improve this answer would be to use `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` to switch to the `IFRAME`s.

Comment: @JeffC Agreed. kajalkundu had written something similar. I will add as an edit to end.