# Python Selenium find element by tag name not working?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find `<select>` elements in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

There are several select elements on this page, but selenium seems to find none of them.

This is the simplest version of my problem:

```py
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

selects_elements = driver.find_elements(by="tag name", value="select")
assert len(selects_elements) > 0
```

I expect this assertion to pass yet it doesn't. Similar problem when finding any of the `<selects>`s by id (e.g. `#pet-select`)

Probably related behaviour I can't explain:

run

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("select")
```

In the browser console in this page. It returns an empty array.
Click "Select an element to inspect" dev tool, then click on a `<select>`.

Run the same javascript in the console.
Now it returns an array with this `<select>` in it.

I have tried a `time.sleep(10)` with no result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530678/unable-to-find-element-in-selenium had a similar problem I will post my solution

Comment: that's not how name works. that will select an element like `<p name="select">`

Comment: @pguardiario "tag name" selects by what tag it is, "name" selects by the property "name" of the tag https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=tag%20name#selenium.webdriver.common.by.By

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. You should probably use CssSelector though since it's the one that always works properly.

Comment: This method worked, I just had to switch the driver to the iframe it was contained in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element(s) I was looking for was inside of an iframe. I needed to switch the driver to this frame before it could find it.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select")

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.switch_to.frame(
    driver.find_element(
        by=By.XPATH, value="""//*[@id="content"]/article/section[1]/div/iframe"""
    )
)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="output-iframe"))

selects_element = Select(driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="pet-select"))
print([option.text for option in selects_element.options])
```